# how to delete child row only in jquery datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a 2 row staticly its a default. and i want to add more rows in below the default rows.. and i dont knwo how to delete child row without deleting parent row..

> My parent row is that default two rows. i dont want to delete that two rows.. i want to delete child rows only..

```js
var ctr = 1;
var FieldCount = 1;
$('#cashTable').on('click', '.button-add', function() {
  ctr++;
  var cashacc_code = 'cashacc_code' + ctr;
  var cashacc = 'cashacc' + ctr;
  var cash_narrat = 'cash_narrat' + ctr;
  var cashdeb = 'cashdeb' + ctr;
  var cashcredit = 'cashcredit' + ctr;
  var newTr = '<tr class="jsrow"><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cashacc_code + ' placeholder="NNNN" /></td><td><select class="form-control" id="cashacc" ><option value="">Choose an Items</option><option value="1">Joe</option><option value="2">Joe</option><option value="3">Joe</option></select></td><td><input type="text" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cash_narrat + ' placeholder="Enter Here" /></td><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cashdeb + ' ' + FieldCount + ' placeholder="NNNN" /></td><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cashcredit + ' /></td><td style="width: 4%"><img src="./img/plus.svg" class="insrt-icon button-add"><img src="./img/delete.svg" class="dlt-icon"></td></tr>';
  $('#cashTable').append(newTr);
  // delete row
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dlt-icon').click(DeleteRow);
  });

  function DeleteRow() {
    $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<table id="cashTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" required>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A/c Code</th>
      <th>Account Name*</th>
      <th>Narration*</th>
      <th>Debit*</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="fst_row">
      <!-- First row -->
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="cashacc_code" placeholder="NNNN" class="form-control" name="cashacc_code" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="cashacc" id="cashacc">
          <option value="Choose and items">Choose and items</option>
          <option value="1">TDS A/c Name 1</option>
          <option value="2">TDS A/c Name 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="cash_narrat" placeholder="Enter here" class="form-control" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,20}" name="cash_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="cashdeb" placeholder="Debit Amount" class="form-control" name="cashdeb" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="cashcredit" class="form-control" name="cashcredit" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 4%">
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/plus.svg" class="insrt-icon button-add"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/delete.svg" class="dlt-icon button-add"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Second Row -->

    <tr id="sndRow">
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="rowNum" name="cashaccCode" placeholder="NNNN" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="cashacc_nme" id="cashacc_nme">
          <option value="#">Choose and items</option>
          <option value="1">Joe</option>
          <option value="2">Joe2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_narrat" placeholder="Enter here" name="acc_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accnarratModal" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="accdeb" placeholder="NNNNNN" name="accdeb" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="accCredit" class="form-control" name="accCredit" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 4%">
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/plus.svg" class="insrt-icon button-add"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/delete.svg" class="dlt-icon"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

> If you arent understand please let me knw..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont want to delete first two row that already created, then use `.jsrow` as below

Another thing that you need to understand is tha use of classes, you added class `button-add` in both button add and remove, so see my code and correct it.

```js
var ctr = 1;
var FieldCount = 1;
$('#cashTable').on('click', '.button-add', function() {
  ctr++;
  var cashacc_code = 'cashacc_code' + ctr;
  var cashacc = 'cashacc' + ctr;
  var cash_narrat = 'cash_narrat' + ctr;
  var cashdeb = 'cashdeb' + ctr;
  var cashcredit = 'cashcredit' + ctr;
  var newTr = '<tr class="jsrow"><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cashacc_code + ' placeholder="NNNN" /></td><td><select class="form-control" id="cashacc" ><option value="">Choose an Items</option><option value="1">Joe</option><option value="2">Joe</option><option value="3">Joe</option></select></td><td><input type="text" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cash_narrat + ' placeholder="Enter Here" /></td><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cashdeb + ' ' + FieldCount + ' placeholder="NNNN" /></td><td><input type="number" class=' + "joe" + ' id=' + cashcredit + ' /></td><td style="width: 4%"><img src="./img/plus.svg" class="insrt-icon button-add"><img src="./img/delete.svg" class="dlt-icon"></td></tr>';
  $('#cashTable').append(newTr);
  // delete row
 

  
});

 $(document).on( 'click', '.dlt-icon', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr.jsrow').first().remove();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="cashTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" required>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A/c Code</th>
      <th>Account Name*</th>
      <th>Narration*</th>
      <th>Debit*</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="fst_row">
      <!-- First row -->
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="cashacc_code" placeholder="NNNN" class="form-control" name="cashacc_code" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="cashacc" id="cashacc">
          <option value="Choose and items">Choose and items</option>
          <option value="1">TDS A/c Name 1</option>
          <option value="2">TDS A/c Name 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="cash_narrat" placeholder="Enter here" class="form-control" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,20}" name="cash_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="cashdeb" placeholder="Debit Amount" class="form-control" name="cashdeb" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="cashcredit" class="form-control" name="cashcredit" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 4%">
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/plus.svg" class="insrt-icon button-add"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/delete.svg" class="dlt-icon "></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Second Row -->

    <tr id="sndRow">
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="rowNum" name="cashaccCode" placeholder="NNNN" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="cashacc_nme" id="cashacc_nme">
          <option value="#">Choose and items</option>
          <option value="1">Joe</option>
          <option value="2">Joe2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_narrat" placeholder="Enter here" name="acc_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accnarratModal" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="accdeb" placeholder="NNNNNN" name="accdeb" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="accCredit" class="form-control" name="accCredit" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 4%">
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/plus.svg" class="insrt-icon button-add"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="./img/delete.svg" class="dlt-icon"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much bro.. its working.. but childrens row add button is not working.. only delete button is working on childrens row..

Comment: @Joe see in demo, its adding when click on first button.